# JSONObject.put string method adding extra \ character to JSON String

Tags: android, json

I have a json string which has pid, name, price as elements. I'm displaying it in logcat. But this string changes as i use the put method to add a json string to json object. When i print the json object '\' charcater is added to every key value pair. I'm not able to figure out what is actually causing the problem.

json is a plain string and jObj is JSONObject.

My logcat details are:

```
json = {"products":[{"pid":"14","name":"zxc","price":"123456"},{"pid":"6","name":"Sony Xperia","price":"35000"},{"pid":"8","name":"Samsung Galaxy Note","price":"32000"},{"pid":"5","name":"htc","price":"26326"},{"pid":"9","name":"Nokia Lumia 800","price":"18000"},{"pid":"2","name":"iphone","price":"12345"},{"pid":"15","name":"sdjnas","price":"12243"},{"pid":"13","name":"Samsung S5222","price":"6500"},{"pid":"11","name":"Nokia C201","price":"4400"},{"pid":"7","name":"Nokia Asha 200","price":"4000"},{"pid":"1","name":"htc","price":"1234"},{"pid":"3","name":"htc","price":"1234"},{"pid":"4","name":"htc","price":"1234"},{"pid":"10","name":"aks","price":"1234"},{"pid":"12","name":"asd","price":"123"}],"success":1}
```

After writing the following line of code :

```
jObj.put("details", json);
```

An extra character '\' is added.

```
json object = {"details":"{\"products\":[{\"pid\":\"14\",\"name\":\"zxc\",\"price\":\"123456\"},{\"pid\":\"6\",\"name\":\"Sony Xperia\",\"price\":\"35000\"},{\"pid\":\"8\",\"name\":\"Samsung Galaxy Note\",\"price\":\"32000\"},{\"pid\":\"5\",\"name\":\"htc\",\"price\":\"26326\"},{\"pid\":\"9\",\"name\":\"Nokia Lumia 800\",\"price\":\"18000\"},{\"pid\":\"2\",\"name\":\"iphone\",\"price\":\"12345\"},{\"pid\":\"15\",\"name\":\"sdjnas\",\"price\":\"12243\"},{\"pid\":\"13\",\"name\":\"Samsung S5222\",\"price\":\"6500\"},{\"pid\":\"11\",\"name\":\"Nokia C201\",\"price\":\"4400\"},{\"pid\":\"7\",\"name\":\"Nokia Asha 200\",\"price\":\"4000\"},{\"pid\":\"1\",\"name\":\"htc\",\"price\":\"1234\"},{\"pid\":\"3\",\"name\":\"htc\",\"price\":\"1234\"},{\"pid\":\"4\",\"name\":\"htc\",\"price\":\"1234\"},{\"pid\":\"10\",\"name\":\"aks\",\"price\":\"1234\"},{\"pid\":\"12\",\"name\":\"asd\",\"price\":\"123\"}],\"success\":1}\n"}
```

Addition of backslashes is causiing problem in getting the string. JSONException no value for success is shown in logcat :

```
JSONObject json = null;

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try
        {
            int success = json.getInt("success");

            if (success == 1)
            {
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewProductActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The logcat is :

```
05-29 15:54:21.772: W/ThrottleService(91): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
05-29 15:54:26.192: I/ActivityManager(91): START {cmp=com.example.androidhive/.AllProductsActivity} from pid 588
05-29 15:54:26.192: W/WindowManager(91): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21010
05-29 15:54:26.502: I/WindowManager(91): createSurface Window{415a5d70 com.example.androidhive/com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
05-29 15:54:26.543: I/WindowManager(91): createSurface Window{415b8c88     com.example.androidhive/com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity paused=false}: DRAW NOW     PENDING
05-29 15:54:27.002: I/ARMAssembler(35): generated scanline__00000077:03010104_00008001_00000000 [ 89 ipp] (110 ins) at [0x41e00670:0x41e00828] in 1129891 ns
05-29 15:54:27.202: I/ActivityManager(91): Displayed com.example.androidhive/.AllProductsActivity: +980ms
05-29 15:54:27.472: D/dalvikvm(588): GC_CONCURRENT freed 125K, 3% free 10212K/10439K, paused 5ms+4ms
05-29 15:54:27.853: I/JSONPArser.java(588): json = {"products":    [{"pid":"14","name":"zxc","price":"123456"},{"pid":"6","name":"Sony Xperia","price":"35000"},{"pid":"8","name":"Samsung Galaxy Note","price":"32000"},{"pid":"5","name":"htc","price":"26326"},{"pid":"9","name":"Nokia Lumia 800","price":"18000"},{"pid":"2","name":"iphone","price":"12345"},{"pid":"15","name":"sdjnas","price":"12243"},{"pid":"13","name":"Samsung S5222","price":"6500"},{"pid":"11","name":"Nokia C201","price":"4400"},{"pid":"7","name":"Nokia Asha 200","price":"4000"},{"pid":"1","name":"htc","price":"1234"},{"pid":"3","name":"htc","price":"1234"},{"pid":"4","name":"htc","price":"1234"},{"pid":"10","name":"aks","price":"1234"},{"pid":"12","name":"asd","price":"123"}],"success":1}
05-29 15:54:27.892: I/JSONPArser.java(588): json object = {"details":"{\"products\":[{\"pid\":\"14\",\"name\":\"zxc\",\"price\":\"123456\"},{\"pid\":\"6\",\"name\":\"Sony Xperia\",\"price\":\"35000\"},{\"pid\":\"8\",\"name\":\"Samsung Galaxy Note\",\"price\":\"32000\"},{\"pid\":\"5\",\"name\":\"htc\",\"price\":\"26326\"},{\"pid\":\"9\",\"name\":\"Nokia Lumia 800\",\"price\":\"18000\"},{\"pid\":\"2\",\"name\":\"iphone\",\"price\":\"12345\"},{\"pid\":\"15\",\"name\":\"sdjnas\",\"price\":\"12243\"},{\"pid\":\"13\",\"name\":\"Samsung S5222\",\"price\":\"6500\"},{\"pid\":\"11\",\"name\":\"Nokia C201\",\"price\":\"4400\"},{\"pid\":\"7\",\"name\":\"Nokia Asha 200\",\"price\":\"4000\"},{\"pid\":\"1\",\"name\":\"htc\",\"price\":\"1234\"},{\"pid\":\"3\",\"name\":\"htc\",\"price\":\"1234\"},{\"pid\":\"4\",\"name\":\"htc\",\"price\":\"1234\"},{\"pid\":\"10\",\"name\":\"aks\",\"price\":\"1234\"},{\"pid\":\"12\",\"name\":\"asd\",\"price\":\"123\"}],\"success\":1}\n"}
05-29 15:54:27.892: I/JSONPArser.java(588): Line 27
05-29 15:54:27.902: I/JSONPArser.java(588): Line 30
05-29 15:54:27.902: D/All Products:(588): {"details":"{\"products\":[{\"pid\":\"14\",\"name\":\"zxc\",\"price\":\"123456\"},{\"pid\":\"6\",\"name\":\"Sony Xperia\",\"price\":\"35000\"},{\"pid\":\"8\",\"name\":\"Samsung Galaxy Note\",\"price\":\"32000\"},{\"pid\":\"5\",\"name\":\"htc\",\"price\":\"26326\"},{\"pid\":\"9\",\"name\":\"Nokia Lumia 800\",\"price\":\"18000\"},{\"pid\":\"2\",\"name\":\"iphone\",\"price\":\"12345\"},{\"pid\":\"15\",\"name\":\"sdjnas\",\"price\":\"12243\"},{\"pid\":\"13\",\"name\":\"Samsung S5222\",\"price\":\"6500\"},{\"pid\":\"11\",\"name\":\"Nokia C201\",\"price\":\"4400\"},{\"pid\":\"7\",\"name\":\"Nokia Asha 200\",\"price\":\"4000\"},{\"pid\":\"1\",\"name\":\"htc\",\"price\":\"1234\"},{\"pid\":\"3\",\"name\":\"htc\",\"price\":\"1234\"},{\"pid\":\"4\",\"name\":\"htc\",\"price\":\"1234\"},{\"pid\":\"10\",\"name\":\"aks\",\"price\":\"1234\"},{\"pid\":\"12\",\"name\":\"asd\",\"price\":\"123\"}],\"success\":1}\n"}
05-29 15:54:27.933: W/System.err(588): org.json.JSONException: No value for success
05-29 15:54:27.933: W/System.err(588):  at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
05-29 15:54:27.933: W/System.err(588):  at org.json.JSONObject.getInt(JSONObject.java:443)
05-29 15:54:27.942: W/System.err(588):  at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:110)
05-29 15:54:27.942: W/System.err(588):  at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:1)
05-29 15:54:27.973: W/System.err(588):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
05-29 15:54:27.973: W/System.err(588):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
05-29 15:54:27.973: W/System.err(588):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-29 15:54:27.973: W/System.err(588):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
05-29 15:54:27.973: W/System.err(588):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
05-29 15:54:27.982: W/System.err(588):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
05-29 15:54:27.982: W/System.err(588):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Doesn't "details" convert to \"details\"?

Comment: @Sufian no it wasn't. I have directly pasted here the value of jObj.

Comment: Hint: character escape: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski what do you exactly wanna point out?

Comment: @AkshaySoam that the slashes are `escape characters`.

Comment: that i know @Sufian but the thing is logcat shows jsonexception:no value for success but you can see it is present at the last but i think the slashes are creating a problem.

Comment: @AkshaySoam slashes are NOT the problem. `LogCat` always shows JSON string like that.

Comment: @AkshaySoam code seems fine. Can you copy-paste the `LogCat`?

Comment: @Sufian i have added the complete logcat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);

jsonObj.get("products");

JSONObject newJsonObj = new JSONObject();
newJsonObj.put("whatever", jsonObj.get("products"));
```

If you want to keep the json without escaping you need to add the jsonObject to an JsonArray.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put(jsonObj);
```

and get it back later with

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)  { 
    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); 
 // then you can start filtering out the array.
    if (jsonObj.has("products")) {
         JSONArray nJsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonObj.get("products"));
          for (......) {} 
}
```

Comment: @AkshaySoam did you replace `jParser.makeHttpRequest()` line? I'm curious about the type of `jParser`. Please state.

Comment: @Sufian no actually i was receiving the json object in another android activity. I just passed the json string as an argument at the time of declaration in the first activity and then tried getting the "success" and it worked... :)

Comment: @AkshaySoam didn't get what you mean, but it's good that you've fixed the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

That is a functional, good JSONobject. I created one with Cocoa JSON editor and there was no error. I don't know what it adds those backslashes, but I can tell you it's okey

Comment: but i have problem getting the values. For example the compiler says there's no value for "success"  but you can see it is present at the last of the string but with an extra slash. So i have a problem retreiving string from it.

Comment: @AkshaySoam please post the code where you are accessing "success".